# How to increment product quantity in Grid Control, if said product is available and more of it is added

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a control grid that I work with, which is affiliated with the `Dev Express Library`

And I continued a method when adding a new item. The quantity is only increased if it is in the `Grid Control`.

The problem is that when I initially add an item, it is added without issues, but if I add it again, it is added in a separate row.

After the quantity is increased on the two similar rows, I only want the row to be added once, and when adding again, the quantity is increased without adding a new row.

```
bool Found = false;
if (gridView1.RowCount > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= gridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        int col1 = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "id"));
        if (Convert.ToInt32(col1) == Convert.ToInt32(tblItems.Rows[0][0]))
        {
            int col2 = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "qty"));
            gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "qty", Convert.ToString(1 + Convert.ToInt16(col2)));
            Found = true;
        }
    }
}
if (!Found)
{
    gridView1.AddNewRow();
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["id"], Product_ID);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["item"], Product_Name);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["size"], Product_Unit);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["qty"], Product_Qty);

    tblUnit = db.readData("select * from Products where Pro_ID=" + categoryID + "", "");
    decimal realPrice = 0;
    try
    {
        realPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(tblUnit.Rows[0][7]);
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["price"], realPrice);

    decimal total = Convert.ToDecimal(Product_Qty) * Convert.ToDecimal(realPrice);

    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["total"], total);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["Product_Group_ID"], Product_Group_ID);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["print"], Product_PRINTNAME);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["protax"], Product_tax);
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(GridControl.NewItemRowHandle, gridView1.Columns["Note"], " ");

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you clarify your question, please? Maybe this could be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should define a BindingList to add the order details to it and set the grid data source to the BindingList,
then you add or modify the BindingList and the grid will automatically reflect the changes